# Calculate value in Group By statement

Tags: grafana, prometheus, promql

**Use case:**

I have 10 Kubernetes nodes (consider them as VMs) which have between 7 and 14 allocatable CPU cores which can be requested by Kubernetes pods. Therefore I'd like to show a table which shows the

1. Allocatable CPU cores
2. The requested CPU cores
3. The ratio of requested / allocatable CPU cores

grouped by node.

**The problem**

Creating the table for the first 2 requirements was easy. I simply created a table in Grafana and added these two metrics:

```
sum(kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores) by (node)
sum(kube_node_status_allocatable_cpu_cores) by (node)
```

However I was struggling with the third one. I tried this query, but it didn't return any data apparently:

```
sum(kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores / kube_node_status_allocatable_cpu_cores) by (node)
```

**Question**

How can I achieve a calculation of two different metrics in a group by statement in my given example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that the two have different labels, so you need to aggregate away the extras:

```
  sum by (node)(kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores) 
/ 
  sum by (node)(kube_node_status_allocatable_cpu_cores)
```